# Can't mount /data, /cache, and /sdcard

Tags: internal-storage, unbricking, partitions

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 2, (device ID is 2014813) and there is a serious problem going on with it.

This morning I saw a message from the phone, saying that the full encryption was unsuccessful, and all my data is inaccessible now, so I have to do a factory reset. I booted up into recovery, tried to do a factory reset, but it said that it couldn't mount `/data`, `/cache`, and even `/sdcard`.

I tried flashing in fastboot with MiFlash, without any luck, it fails at setting up the partition table. ADB sideload works, but I can't do much with it, because even if I install a ROM with it, I can't boot that ROM up.

I NEVER wanted to do an encryption on this device, I don't know why did it do that.

Comment: That seems strange. Why would a device begin full disk encryption if a user didn't initiate it? Anyhow, when the device tells you that encryption is unsuccessful, does it provide an option to erase/reset the device? If yes, then did you try it? For example, in my Nexus 6, when I choose that option it boots into a certain screen where it shows "Erasing Data". It is different from stock recovery. May be your device also has such provision.

Comment: Yes, there was a button, and that "sent" me to the recovery, but it didn't begin erasing by itself. Neither the recovery, nor the ROM was stock; I've used a CM12.1, with TWRP recovery. I know it's strange, I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: At first, I thought it's a bug, and I rebooted the phone. Then this "message" showed up again, and then I pressed that button, and I did a factory reset in the recovery.

Comment: Try flashing a stock ROM that will have the partition info.

Comment: I'm trying that since yesterday morning. I just type in: fastboot flash partition *partition table file*, and it always says: "FAILED (remote: failed to write partition)". I don't wanna give up on this device, I really liked it.

Comment: It's not like the samsung's ODIN files. It would be the best for me to have one big file, what I can just flash, and it would set up everything by itself. But there are separate files, and one that sets up the partition table. And I just can't flash that file

Comment: @Gabe Did you try installing New MIUI ROM from the miui forum.? Download ROM [here](http://en.miui.com/download-261.html)

Comment: If official firmware flasher doesn't work, possibility is that your eMMC is corrupted / dead.

Comment: Exactly. That was the case, hardware fault. Phone got sent back to reseller, and they replaced the entire device. Apparently it wasn't an uncommon issue, a few other people had similar experience, and all they could do is getting a use out of their warranty.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Using adb

   create a folder named `external_sd in /sdcard/`  with your file manager

   Use  this code in **commamd prompt (adb)** (to make this folder to mount sd card in /sdcard/):

su

```
    mount -o bind /mnt/emmc /sdcard/external_sd
```

2. Alternatively via terminal (need busybox installed and root):

   `busybox mount --bind /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard/external_sd` (as su)

Credits

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1724278